# What is a spinach head is equal to?

Tags: measurements, conversion, spinach

I have a recipe for ravioli filling that calls for a head of spinach. Can anyone translate into ounces or bunches please?

Comment: Hi Sandy, welcome to Seasoned Advice! My advice to you is to find a different recipe. Somebody might come along with a better answer, though.

Comment: Spinach doesn't grow in heads (like lettuce). Each plant has just a few leaves. This makes the "head" measurement very unusual/non-standard.

Comment: Is it likely that the recipe has been translated into English, or written by a non-native speaker? It's plausible that this was just a bad choice of words, when they should've said "bunch".

Comment: I'd go with the other answerers and say it is probably a mistranslation. Can you supply us with the full text of the recipe? That often helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that in this case what is described as a "head", is actually a "bunch".  Spinach is typically sold in a bunch (or already prepared and bagged...or frozen), as it doesn't grow in "heads."  Further, there is probably no need to be very precise for a ravioli filling recipe, and I am guessing this filling has other ingredients.  You probably want to avoid frozen for the pasta filling.  It could work, but is often very wet once thawed.

Comment: Any spinach is pretty wet if you don’t squeeze it out well in a sieve or a cloth.